# Wie wird das Wort "erwarten" benutzt?

Tags: standard-german

*Erwarten* hat viele Bedeutungen, wenn es sich auf "hoffen", "den Wunsch haben" richtet. Ist es im folgenden richtig?

> Ich erwarte (von jm)，dass ...
>    Ich erwarte mir viel von dir.

Muss "mir" begleitet werden?

Answer (score 2):

Man kann beide Sätze so verwenden.

Was das Wort "mir" in

> Ich erwarte mir viel von dir.

angeht, so kann man es auch weglassen. Man kann es verwenden, um die Betonung des Satzes auf die eigene Erwartung/Gefühle (bzw. deren Erfüllung) zu lenken. Die Erfüllung der Erwartung bewirkt etwas (positives) *für* mich. Dem gegenüber wird die Erwartung beim Weglassen des Wortes eher als eine Erwartungshaltung *gegenüber* der anderen Person geäußert. In diesem Fall geht es eher in die Richtung einer auferlegten Last oder Pflicht und die Handlung, die zur Erfüllung der Erwartung führt steht im Vordergrund.